# Python. Сдвиг в цикле

Tags: python, list, словарь

Имеется некоторый цикл по элементам из списка, которые вызывают функции по словарю

```
 data = list(param)
 for char in data:
  switch[hex(ord(char))].__call__()
```

Как задать условие, что бы на (к примеру) 13 символе бралось в другой список (к примеру) 10 символов, которые передавались бы в последующем в функцию, а char, при этом, сдвигался бы на 10 ?

Comment: Мне кажется вы очень усложняете задачу.. опишите что вы хотите сделать

Comment: @AlexZaharchuk, для начала просто сдвинуть индекс положения char в текущий момент, это как если бы можно было char[13] сдвинуть на char[22]

Comment: Используйте цикл не по элементу, а по индексу.